# RelativeLayout: what's wrong with the baseline alignment?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout that would look like this:

[image: The desired layout]

*(The dotted lines are baselines of the text views.)*

So the main anchor is the large *W*, then *abc* is baseline-aligned to *W*, and then *def* is above *abc*.

But when I set the baseline alignment for *abc*, the *def* falls down and gets invisible.  There is no problem with *abc*, it is aligned perfectly.

I've found the only way to make *def* visible: it is changing the alignment for *abc* so it would be aligned to the bottom of *W*, but that looks bad because the larger glyph has a greater bottom margin (more vertical space between the baseline and the bottom edge of the view).

It looks like the baseline alignment is handled some special way so the layout cannot calculate the right position for dependent views.

Do I do something wrong?  Is my layout ever possible?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/w"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="W"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/w"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/def"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="def"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout XML?

Comment: Sure, done.  It's very simple so I thought my original explanation is enough.

Comment: It was, but sometimes people make little mistakes that they miss -- not that I'm saying you have...

Comment: @JosephEarl wise words... very wise words :)

Comment: @AlexanderDunaev, my answer works?

Comment: @Marckaraujo, it does something that looks similar to what I need, but it doesn't answer my question about the baseline alignment. And it is hard to support. In my real application, the font sizes differ, and the layout is embedded into another view. I don't want to tune the pixels, I want the layout manager to align the text on baseline.

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable but not perfect workaround is here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/M9THu9V08vo/EouuJZv1dTAJ

> However, that led me to find a little quirk, if you align B to A using simultaneous layout_alignBottom and  layout_alignBaseline flags, then C’s positioning now works, it happily sits above B exactly as if just layout_alignBottom was being used, although B is still aligned to A’s baseline. The caveat is that C’s positioning is sligthty lower than normal; it behaves as if the B is aligned to A’s bottom, then C is positioned, and then B is realigned to A’s baseline, without C changing position. However I can get round that with some margin offsets, and at least it can be done via XML.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, at least in API 10 emulator.  C doesn't want to stay above B.  But I confirm that adding the layout_alignBottom flag to B's attributes somehow affects the vertical position of C: if I set that flag, C moves up a bit, but absolutely not enough.

Thank you for your discovery anyway.

FYI, I no longer suffer the issue because I've changed my layout so it doesn't align the views that way.